# Why is EntityManager not injected via @PersistenceContext within Tomcat8 environment?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jpa

I have some service to persist object to context and face a null `EntityManager` when run it

```
@Stateless
public class PointServies {

@PersistenceContext(name="pointProvider",type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
private EntityManager em;

public void addMovie(Point point) throws Exception {
    em.persist(point); // em is null here.
}
}
```

this is my persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence

http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"

version="2.1">

<persistence-unit name="pointProvider">

    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <class>model.Point</class>

    <properties>
        <!-- Configuring JDBC properties -->
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />

        <!-- Hibernate properties -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

looks like `PersistenceContext` can't find my xml.....
The `persistence.xml` exist in "src/META-INF/persistence.xml"
and all the other sources reside in "src/model/Point"

I try to run this project on Tomcat 8 web-container.

Comment: And when you deploy war, what tomcat writes in log file?

Comment: Tomcat8 has no support for CDI,and no support for EJBs. You need a full-stack application server: JBoss, Glassfish, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat doesn't support EJB by default, i reccommand you either [add the OpenEJB webapp to Tomcat](http://tomee.apache.org/manual-installation.html), or use full-stack application server like [GlassFish](https://glassfish.java.net/) or [WebLogic Server](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/downloads/wls-main-097127.html).